# Can two HomeKit homes share one Philip Hue Bridge?

Tags: homekit, iot

I have one [Hue Bridge V2](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/support/release-notes/bridge) (the square HomeKit-enabled one) and it's all working fine in HomeKit.

Today I installed two more lights and I want to share them with my roommate. But the problem is that the lights only show up in my home in the Home app, instead of showing up in my roommate's home.

Is it possible to assign lights from one Hue Bridge to two or more different HomeKit homes?

Comment: Phillips or Apple?